# Were companies required to issue pandemic flight vouchers in the US?

Tags: usa, covid-19, cancellations

Back when the pandemic first landed in the US, we cancelled some flights that we had booked.  The company we booked through offered us vouchers that ostensibly expired at the end of this year (9 months in the future).  However, now, the company refuses to honor these vouchers.  Were there any requirements/rules back then by the DOT/feds/states that airlines/travel companies allow customers to reschedule their flights, or am I strictly at the company's whim on this?

Comment: Is "the company" an actual airline, a third-party booking website, a travel agency, a package tour company, or what?  Are they still in business?  Did they give a reason for their refusal to honor the voucher?

Comment: In what country is "the company" located? From where and to where were to flights to have occurred?

Comment: Did you indeed cancel the flights on your own initiative, or were the flights cancelled by the airline (**before** you cancelled them)? Did the airline at the time publish a rebooking/change policy? Do you have a trace of it? It may stil be available via the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org) if you're lucky.

Comment: Also, I’m surprised that they issued vouchers expiring at the end of 2021. Most airlines tried very hard to limit validity of vouchers either to end of 2020 or one year from the date of cancellation, or even one year from the initial date of purchase.

Comment: US.  It's a third-party booking website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> we cancelled some flights that we had booked.

That's a problem. If the airline cancels, you are (in most countries) entitled to a full refund. If you cancel on your own, the cancellation is governed by the terms & conditions of the original ticket. Depending on the ticket, these can vary greatly, so you need to look those up.

> The company we booked through offered us vouchers

Did the terms of the ticket specifies voucher or travel credit (after applicable fees) in case of cancellation? What are the exact terms of the vouchers?

> Were there any requirements/rules back then by the DOT/feds/states that airlines/travel companies allow customers to reschedule their flights,

Not that I'm aware of. The governments intervened strongly to discourage the airlines from giving vouchers instead of cash refunds for airline cancellation, but passenger cancellation was typically left to the airlines with maybe some governmental nudging. Many airlines did indeed offer free rebooking, vouchers or credit, but with greatly varying terms, rules, and flexibility.

> or am I strictly at the company's whim on this?

Not exactly. Tickets and vouchers come with terms and conditions, rules, and exclusions etc. which govern what can and cannot be done. The company is unlikely to just straight out refuse a voucher that they previously issued. They would typically give a reason and that reason would be based on some of these terms & rules. Your best shot is to assess whether their reason for refusal is valid and justified by the original contracts (that you indeed accepted).